# Printing PDF using Wifi-Direct from Android to HP Mobile Printer is producing gibberish while it works for the HP desktop printer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, wifi-direct

I am using Wifi-Direct to send a PDF file from an Android app to HP Mobile Printer. While it works for the HP desktop printers, it currently produces gibberish (raw PostScript) for a HP Mobile Printer.

I am using a C# version of the sample Android app. I am using the port 9100. The app writes the data into the socket's output stream. Should I use the port 631? What am I missing here?

```
                var fileUri = uri?.ToString();
                var host = (_info?.GroupOwnerAddress?.HostAddress);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(host))
                    return;
                var port = (9100);//631;
```

```
                        // Open the File where its located 
                        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(uri.Path);
                        length = file.Length();
                        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

```
                    mmOutputStream = socket.OutputStream;

                    await CopyFileJava(mmOutputStream, inputStream, length);
```

```
        private static void CopyFileJava(OutputStream mmOutputStream, FileInputStream inputStream)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = inputStream.Read(bytes)) > 0)
            {
                mmOutputStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The distinguishing  factor here appears to be the printer.
I know nothing about the HP Mobile Printer line but I would look to see whether they recognize Postscript by default or that needs to be expressly specified.

Comment: What driver is installed for the printer?  You may of download the wrong type driver.  The driver may not be postscript.  Drivers can be PLC or Postscript.

Comment: That too is entirely possible.